# How do I group or summarize multiple rows where multiple column values are the same using MSSQL2017

Tags: grouping, sql-server-2017

I would like to summarize the data in this table to calculate the total NumberOfPallets which have the same content

ie

15 Pallets which contain the following:

Item   Colour    Packing    QtyPerPallet

Item1  Red       FOIL       35
Item2  Blue      FOIL       110

2 Pallets which contain the following:

Item   Colour    Packing    QtyPerPallet

Item1  Red       PLASTIC    35
Item3  Yellow    PLASTIC    50

I have no idea where to begin!

CREATE TABLE Orders
     (SalesOrder INT NOT NULL,
     PalletNo INT NOT NULL,
     Item CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     Colour CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
     Packing CHAR(10) not Null,
     QtyPerPallet INT Not Null,
     NumberOfPallets INT not Null)

INSERT INTO Orders
 (SalesOrder, PalletNo, Item, Colour,Packing, QtyPerPallet, NumberOfPallets)
 VALUES
 (1, 22, 'ITEM1', 'RED', 'FOIL', 35,5),
 (1, 22, 'ITEM2', 'BLUE', 'FOIL',110,5),
 (112, 47, 'ITEM2', 'BLUE', 'FOIL',110,10),
 (112, 47, 'ITEM1', 'RED', 'FOIL',35,10),
(217,1100, 'ITEM1', 'RED', 'PLASTIC', 35,2),
(217,1100, 'ITEM3', 'YELLOW', 'PLASTIC', 50, 2)

Answer (score 0):

based on what I understand from your question , it helps to know what you want your final output to look like

but let me know if this works

```
select 

item
,colour
,packing
,QtyPerPallet
,count(distinct palletNo) number_of_pallets


from 
orders

group by 
item
,colour
,packing
,QtyPerPallet
```

Comment: Thanks for the code...BUT...its a little more complex. I almost need to assign a unique "Key" to each "Pallet Type" where the contents are exactly the same. So in my example, PalletNo 22 and 47 have the same content in terms of Item, Colour, Packing and PiecesPerPallet, and the total number of pallets to construct should be 15.  PalletNo 1100 is also a unique construct, even though there is an Item which is common to the other 2 pallets.  Hope all this makes sense !